# Windows Phone Profiling and high memory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, profiling, windows-phone

I'm currently creating a Windows Phone app and I'm having issues limiting the amount of memory being used. I'm using the built-in tools for Windows Phone profiling.

The app does the following at the same time:
* An API call on the background (parse the result using the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library)
* Calculate the objects to be displayed and when the calculation is completed, bind it.

The problem is, the amount of memory is really high. It uses average about 80-90 MB with peeks over 90 MB (this app has to be in the store).

An App execution analysis shows the following notes: both a high memory usage by system threads and managed threads. It also says the memory is "Texture dominant".
So I did a memory analysis.

[Album of profiling](http://imgur.com/a/8jSKQ%5d)

The profiler notes a "high amount of texture allocations in the memory". Most of the time this is about 50%.
*Question about this: are textures also custom user controls? I remember reading something that every user control is being saved as bitmap in memory*

When I take a look at the Heap Summary, it shows a couple of high values.
*How should I interpret this data? How should the numbers be compared to eachother?*

Taking a look at the Types, String uses 13%. Does this mean String is using the most memory?

Does this mean Strings are using the most memory or not? Or am I looking at the wrong place where the most memory is being used? Should I look at, for example, the "Retained Visuals at the Start" in the Heap summary?
If I look there, some of the values are being caused by my own written user controls. 
I'm using a Listbox (because it supports UI Virtualization), but I'm using my own controls as the ListboxItem. Should I replace them with a Listboxitem?

I can't find a clear tutorial on how to use profiling tools :-( And personally I find it hard to understand (for example, if you compare it to the Android profiling tools).

**TL;DR: Help understanding profiling tools and trying to find what is using so much memory**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have too many images in your app? most of the time high memory is caused by not properly adapted images or bad practices.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
There are no images used. I removed them to find out if that was the reason of the high memory usage.